# Bulk create many-to-many objects to self

Tags: python, django

Having model

```py
class MyTable(Model):
     close = ManyToManyField("MyTable")
```

How to bulk create objects to this relation?

With tables not related to itself, one could use

```py
db_payload  =[MyTable.close.throught(tablea_id=x, tableb_id=y) for x,y in some_obj_list]
MyTable.close.through.objects.bulk_create(db_payload)
```

What would the keyword arguments be in case where relation is to the table itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case it uses as fields `from_model` and `to_model`. Indeed, we can see this in the [source code <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/6ad0dbc8d90ef37731608f7ac3d6e1d62cc8c765/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L1275C1-L1279C34):

> ```
> to = make_model_tuple(to_model)[1]
> from_ = klass._meta.model_name
> if to == from_:
>     to = "to_%s" % to
>     from_ = "from_%s" % from_
> ```

So you can work with:

```
MyTable.close.through.objects.bulk_create(
    [
        MyTable.close.through(from_mytable_id=x, to_mytable_id=y)
        for x, y in some_obj_list
    ]
)
```